# No se generan etiquetas al hacer .map a un state

Tags: reactjs, map

En la primer imagen obtengo los valores de laravel y los asigno al state, aclaro que los datos si son recibidos de ante mano.

En la segunda es donde deberia generar todas las etiquetas y no se muestra nada ni marca ningun error en consola como muestro en la tercer imagen.

Agradecería mucho la ayuda.

---

*Llamo los datos de una API en laravel y los asigno al state, aclaro que al imprimir en consola si se muestran los datos*

[image: Llamo los datos de una API en laravel y los asigno al state, aclaro que al imprimir en consola si se muestran los datos]

---

*Donde genero las etiquetas generadas por el `.map`*

[image: Donde genero las etiquetas generadas por el .map]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Procura que los datos relevantes a tu pregunta (código, mensajes de error, datos de prueba) estén como texto, no como imágenes, pues hace más fácil que otros prueben / repliquen, busquen respuestas para tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Por poner un pero, *this.setState* es asíncrono, estas haciendo el console.log justo después, pero sin certeza de que el setState haya realmente funcionado, prueba con esto:

```
...
.then((lista)  => 
  this.setState({ lista },() => {
    console.log(this.state.lista);
  });
})
```